# Is it possible to retrieve attribute names matching certain condition using xpath1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

```
<Tasks>
 <Task>
  <UID>14</UID>
  <Name>Entertainment</Name>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <PerComp>22</PerComp>
 </Task>
 <Task>
  <UID>12</UID>
  <Name>Movie</Name>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <PerComp>55</PerComp>
 </Task>
 <Task>
  <UID>15</UID>
  <Name>Star</Name>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <PerComp>100</PerComp>
 </Task>
</Tasks>
```

Is it possible to list all task names in comma separator from the above XML with condition PerComp not equal to 100? There may be 100's of tasks and I want all task names?

Expected result:

```
Entertainment, Movie, etc.
```

Comment: You added the xquery tag, so why do you limit the answer to xpath 1.0 in the title? If you can use xpath 2.0+, I will undelete my answer.

Comment: The tool which I am using supports only xpath1.0. As an alternative I am planning to import the xml to sql and try query. So I am looking for possible option either xpath or xquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 allows you to retrieve the set of nodes (which are elements, not attributes - your XML contains no attributes), but it does not allow you to combine their values into a string; that would have to be done by the calling application.

```
//Task[not(PerComp = 100)]/Name
```

Comment: //Task[not(PerComp = '100')]/Name worked for me. Thanks Michael.

Comment: Is it also possible to retrieve remaining nodes if element Name matches certain condition? In above example if element name matches Movie I want all the nodes below that node?

Comment: XPath returns references to nodes in the original document. If you select a node, it still has all its parent, children, and descendant nodes attached to it, so those are also accessible to your application. You can either navigate to those nodes using an API such as DOM or JDOM, or you can execute further XPath expressions to reach them.

Comment: <Task>
  <UID>14</UID>
  <Name>Entertainment</Name>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <PerComp>22</PerComp>
 </Task>. How can I filter only this value by UID condition?? Let's say like /Tasks/Task[@UID='14']. Do we option like this?

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments on an answer. Ask a new question.